# Use ".items" on an ObservableCollection ? (loop through it)

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I got a "well-constituted" ObservableCollection and I'd like to inspect into it.
The definition of it is :

```
private Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>> _DataPools = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>>();
```

(yep it's an obsCol with an obsCol in it, but it IS ok, the problem's not here)

I tried 2 different ways but they both don't work...

1) .Items

```
foreach(ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> obj in _DataPools.Items)
        {
            blablaaaa;
            ....
        }
```

.Items doesn't work but when I look in the C#doc, Items is a valid field... (just like "Count", and "Count" works...)

2) Count + [x] acces :

```
var nbItems = _DataPools.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < nbItems; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Items : " + _DataPools[i].XXX); //XXX = ranom method
        }
```

_DataPools[i] doesn't work but on the web I found a couple of example where it is used oO

I tried a couple of other "exotic" things but I really can't go over it...

Any help will be welcomed !

Thx in advance and sry for my langage, im french -_-
(sry for my president too !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_DataPool` is *not* an observable collection in an observable collection. It's a dictionary that contains observable collections. To get the collections from the dictionary, use [the `Values` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx):

```
foreach (ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> obj in _DataPools.Values)
{
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`_DataPools` is a dictionary, not an ObservableCollection.
You need to loop over `.Values`.

Comment: All answers saying almost the same thing, my vote goes to the earliest.

Comment: I'll only answer here but thanks to you all !
I'm really tired... :(

Answer (score 0):

_DataPools is of type Dictionary. you can access the elements of a dictionary with `Values` property.

```
foreach(ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> obj in _DataPools.Values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Dictionary, therefore you should use the property Keys to loop on keys and Values to loop on your items. This should work:

```
foreach(ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> obj in _DataPools.Values)
{
    blablaaaa;
    ....
}
```